# what is the right way to use nextauth credential provider to check if the user and password is exist in the database using prisma in nextjs 13?

Tags: typescript, next.js, prisma

I am currently learning NextJS and I have a question. I would like to know the correct method for using NextAuth's credential provider to verify if a user's login credentials exist in a Prisma database, in the context of NextJS 13 and TypeScript. I have attempted to research this on YouTube and Google, but I have not been able to find a clear answer. Some of the example code I have found is difficult to understand. As a result, I have attempted to create my own code. Could someone please review my code and let me know if I am on the right track, or suggest a better approach? Thank you.

```
`import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client';
import NextAuth, { NextAuthOptions } from 'next-auth'
import { compareSync, hashSync } from 'bcryptjs'
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials"
import email from 'next-auth/providers/email'

const prisma = new PrismaClient();

const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  session: {
    strategy: 'jwt',
  },

  providers:[
    CredentialsProvider({
        // The name to display on the sign in form (e.g. "Sign in with...")
        name: "Credentials",
        // `credentials` is used to generate a form on the sign in page.
        // You can specify which fields should be submitted, by adding keys to the `credentials` object.
        // e.g. domain, username, password, 2FA token, etc.
        // You can pass any HTML attribute to the <input> tag through the object.
        credentials: {
          username: { label: "Email", type: "email", placeholder: "jsmith@example.com" },
          password: { label: "Password", type: "password" }
        },
        async authorize(credentials, req) {
          const user = await prisma.user.findUnique({
            where: {
              email: credentials.username
            }
          });

          if (user && compareSync(credentials.password, user.passwordHash)) {
            // Any object returned will be saved in `user` property of the JWT
            return {
              id: user.id,
              name: user.name,
              email: user.email,
            }
          } else {
            // If you return null then an error will be displayed advising the user to check their details.
            return null;
          }
        }
      })
  ],

  pages:{
    signIn: '/auth/signin',
  },

  callbacks: {
    async jwt(token, user, account, profile, isNewUser) {
      if (user) {
        token.id = user.id;
      }

      return token;
    },
    async session(session, token) {
      session.user.id = token.id;
      return session;
    }
  }
}

export default NextAuth(authOptions)`
```